# SpringFox @ApiModelProperty for Optional<LocalDateTime>

Tags: java, spring, option-type, openapi, springfox

I'm trying to use SpringFox 2.8+ to generate a model for class containing `Optional` fields.

Docket configuration has `genericModelSubstitutes(Optional.class)` rule, that perfectly works for `Optional<String>`. But when the type is `Optional<LocalDateTime>`, documentation contains invalid `/definitions/LocalDateTime` reference. In case of regular `LocalDateTime` field default rule works fine and I got `{"type":"string","format":"date-time"}`.

I try to use `@ApiModelProperty` as workaround, but it doesn't affect resulting json. Is there a way to override `Optional` model property definition?

```java
public class MyModel {
    @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "string", example = "abc") // works
    public Optional<String> a;

    @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "string", example = "2019-08-19T15:05:59.785Z") // works
    public LocalDateTime b;

    @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "string", example = "2019-08-19T15:05:59.785Z") // doesn't work :(
    public Optional<LocalDateTime> c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while working with `@ApiParam`. The following change to `Docket` configuration solved the issue for me. Maybe you can give it a try with `@ApiModelProperty`.

```
Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
  .select()
  ...
  .alternateTypeRules(
    newRule(
      typeResolver.resolve(Optional.class, LocalDateTime.class),
      typeResolver.resolve(String.class)
    )
  );
```